# How can I send alerts with different labels to the same receiver in prometheus alert manager config?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I need to route the alert to **dev-receiver** if it has the label  **dbinstance_identifier: '^(dev-db)$'** or **namespace: '^(dev)$**. I don't think the below one works as the bottom one may override the top one. Can I put some **or** operator b/w two labels or something? Thanks in advance.

```
-receiver: 'dev-receiver'
    match_re:
       dbinstance_identifier: '^(dev-db)$'
- receiver: 'dev-receiver'
     match_re:
       namespace: '^(dev)$
```

Comment: Why shouldn't the bottom one work? The notification will be send down to `dev-receiver` if label `dbinstance_identifier` matches `^(dev-db)$` or label `namespace` matches `^(dev)$`. The bottom one will never override the top one. You could set `continue` to `true`, but in this case the notification would just be send two times.

Answer (score 0):

`match_re` and `match` are deprecated in newer version. Use `matchers` instead as follows:

```
- receiver: 'dev-receiver'
  matchers:
    - dbinstance_identifier =~ "^(dev-db)$"
- receiver: 'dev-receiver'
  matchers:
    - namespace =~ "^(dev)$"
```

You can use `continue: true` as stated in the comment of your question.